# How to implement CFGNode with ANTLR4

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, antlr4, context-free-grammar, visitor-pattern

I am struggling on how to implement the following in the best way:

```
public abstract class Expr extends CFGNode {
  ...
}

public abstract class Stmt extends CFGNode {
  ...
}

public class CFGBuilder extends BaseVisitor<CFGNode> {

  public CFGNode visitWhileStmt(@NotNull Parser.WhileStmtContext ctx) {
    Expr nExpr = visit(ctx.expr()); => not working as it returns CFGNode
    Stmt nStmt = visit(ctx.stmt()); => not working as it returns CFGNode
    return new WhileStmt(nExpr, nStmt);
  }
...
```

**Option 1: Always return CFGNode, which contains 2 fields. Depending on the case, we use one of the two fields or both fields.**

```
public abstract class CFGNode {
  public Expr expr;
  public Stmt stmt;
}
...
public CFGNode visitWhileStmt(@NotNull Parser.WhileStmtContext ctx) {
  CFGNode nExpr = visit(ctx.expr());
  CFGNode nStmt = visit(ctx.stmt());
  return new WhileStmt(nExpr.expr, nStmt.stmt);
}
```

**Option 2: Use casting**

```
public abstract class CFGNode {
   // No real fields
}
...
public CFGNode visitWhileStmt(@NotNull Parser.WhileStmtContext ctx) {
  Expr nExpr = (Expr)(visit(ctx.expr());
  Stmt nStmt = (Stmt)(visit(ctx.stmt());
  return new WhileStmt(nExpr, nStmt);
}
```

**Option 3: Use different visitors for each type that can be returned.**

```
public class CFGBuilder extends BaseVisitor<Expr> {
...
public class CFGBuilder extends BaseVisitor<Stmt> {
...
```

Not very sure how this would work.

**Option 4: Maybe there is an even better solution??**

Answer (score 0):

I would choose Option 2.

- Option 1 means that CFGNode contains one field for every Type of AST node. And accessing these fields will produce a NullPointerException (where Option 2 would produce a ClassCastException) so there is no advantage over Option 2.
- Option 3 will afford that you have a visitor for each AST node. And each visitor will mostly implement only one method.

Yet Option 2 will be not sufficient if the result is dependent on the context (a function call could be a statement or an expression, dependent on the result being used or discarded). In this case you will need to pass the expected type down the parse tree. Terrence Parr explains solutions for that in 'The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference'

- use the java call stack (would be Option 2)
- maintain a separate stack (allows to pass information down the parse tree, by pushing it on the stack)
- annotate the parse tree (maintain a map of parse tree nodes to attributes, see `ParseTreeProperty<T>`)